# Laravel Eloquent add data from relationship to response

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database with lamps and images. They have a one to one relationship. I currently get the lamps from the database and send a response to my vue front-end.

My query:

```
$correspondingLamps = Lamp::where(['fitting' => $fitting, 'dimmability' => $dimmable])
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('light_color_code', '=', '2800K')
        ->orWhere('light_color_code', '=', '2700K');
    })
    ->get();
```

My response:

```
foreach ($correspondingLamps as $lamp) {

    $image = [
        'lamp_id' => $lamp->image->lamp_id,
        'path' => $lamp->image->path
    ];

    array_push($images, $image);
}

return response()->json([
    'images' => $images,
    'lamps' => $correspondingLamps
]);
```

But I think this can be done a lot 'cleaner'. Is there an easy way to just get the `image_path` and pass it to my `lamp` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel you should always default to built in functions. Laravel has good serialization features, let Laravel handle that. The easy way, eager load the Image using the `with()` method and it will be automatically [serialized](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays) with the response.

```
return Lamp::where(['fitting' => $fitting, 'dimmability' => $dimmable])
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('light_color_code', '=', '2800K')
            ->orWhere('light_color_code', '=', '2700K');
    })->with('image')
    ->get();
```

This should produce a result similar to this.

```
[
    {// your lamp object
        "id": 1,
        "image": {
            "id": 1
            "path": "some/path"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, just couldn't name it. Thanks!

Comment: bonus points: the = sign in the where query is there by default so you can do where('light_color_code', '2800K')